# how to use prime faces extensions jar file in netbeans webapplication project

Tags: html

I am trying to use exporter feature of primefaces extension so that i can export multiple tables at a time but  . I am getting following error :
The prefix "pe" for element "pe"dataExporter" is not bound.

code goes here

```
 <h:commandLink> 
             <p:graphicImage value="../resources/images/excel.png" title=""/> 
             <pe:dataExporter type="xls" target="dailyShtSts" fileName="DailyCheckList" postProcessor="#{supportCrmIssuesTabController.postProcessXLS}"/> 
        </h:commandLink>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you declared xmlns:pe="http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions" on the tag html?

Anyway you must declare this and add the jars(org.apache... poi-xxx; poi-excelant-xxx; poi-ooxml-xxx; poi-scratchpad-xxx; and the xmlbeans-xxx) at java build path.

PS: xxx represents the version of the jar file.